# modRewrite issues, and modRewrite rules

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Haay!

Have a question about ModRewrite for apace webserver.
recently i have fixed one of my urls:

**Before**: *http://pagename.com/index.php?sideID=home*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1
```

**After** : *http://pagename.com/home*

Now I have a more advanced problem when I want to pass more variables trough URL
to create my blogg.

**currently**: *http://pagename.com/index.php?sideID=blogg&id=12&title=a-great-blog-post*

I would like this to be more clean and structured, I want somthing like:

*http://pagename.com/blogg/12/Gratulerer-FEEL-GOOD-med-ny-hjemmeside*

I have tested something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1&id=$2&title=$3
```

without any success, any anwser leading to my success will be highly aprecciated :)

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1
RewriteRule ^bloggg/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?sideID=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this additional rule:

```
RewriteRule ^blogg/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?sideID=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, but i keep getting this:
The requested URL /blogg/12/Gratulerer-FEEL-GOOD-med-ny-hjemmeside was not found on this server.

Comment: I can open the link now, and this is what the link looks like now: http://somewebsite.com/index.php?sideID=bloggg&id=12&title=This-is-what-i-see

Comment: Are you seeing URL changing in browser? If yes then post your complete .htaccess here in your question. Also make sure there is no other .htaccess anywhere.

Comment: No, the link stays the same if i remove the rule you gave. Nothing really happens.

Comment: But you wrote with my suggested rule you are seeing URL as `http://somewebsite.com/index.php?sideID=bloggg&id=12&title=This-is-what-i-see` is that correct?

Comment: Yeh, that is what I had originally as well. And with your rule nothing really changes far as I can tell. But atleast, it does not crash now or give any sort of error.

Comment: Please try to answer my questions (I asked same question twice but didn't get straight answer).

Comment: But you wrote with my suggested rule you are seeing URL as http://somewebsite.com/index.php?sideID=bloggg&id=12&title=This-is-what-i-see is that correct? YES, that is correct.

Comment: Well in that case you have some other rules also since my rule isn't using `R` flag and cannot change the URL in browser. As I asked above post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: I think there is some missunderstand here. How is that link any diffrent from the one i explained in my first post? This is the link I started with in the first post -> currently: http://pagename.com/index.php?sideID=blogg&id=12&title=a-great-blog-post And this is the link I have now after applying your rule: http://somewebsite.com/index.php?sideID=bloggg&id=12&title=This-is-what-i-see

Comment: And I have posted the full .htaccess above.

Comment: Actually, I tried to enter this as URL now: 
http://somesite.com/bloggg/id/12/Gratulerer-FEEL-GOOD-med-ny-hjemmeside

Then I can see what looks like my index file without any CSS :P

Comment: Right now it is making complete sense :)

Comment: Make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Also I edited to make it `blogg` instead of `bloggg`

Comment: I assume this is not a absolute path: background-image: url("../images/bg1.jpg"); ?

It would have to be something like: 
background-image: url("rootfolder/images/bg1.jpg"); ?

Comment: yes that's correct, always prefer using absolute URL while using prety URL rewrites.

Comment: I will give it a try, a lot of work fixing of that. Thanks for your help ;)